# what does $\langle u,v\rangle$ mean?

Tags: vectors

Firstly, apologies for the very stupid question but I have forgotten what this means.

I have a question I did a  few months back where it says

$u=(1-2i,3,2+i)$ and $v=(i,1-3i,0)$

It asks me to compute

$\langle u,v\rangle$

to which I have put equal to $1+8i$

But i have no idea how I got this, as I cannot remember what it means and never wrote it down anywhere. I have tried a google search to remind myself but cannot find it in this context.

Please could someone advise me what I did to get that? Apologies for the stupid question.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$u=(1-2i,3,2+i)$ and $v=(i,1-3i,0)$

It probably means the inner product of the two vectors:
\begin{align}
& (1-2i)\left(\overline{{}\, i\, {}}\right) + 3\left(\overline{1-3i}\right) +(2+3i)\left(\overline{{}\, 0 \,{}}\right) \\[6pt]
= {} & (1-2i)(-i) + 3(1+3i) + (2+3i)(0).
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for this yes was inner product and indeed gives 1+8i. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Inner product for two vectors $u,v \in \Bbb C^n$.

$\langle u,v\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i\overline v_i$ where $\overline v_i$ denotes the complex conjugate of $v_i$.

Comment: Thanks. what's the mathjax for the inner product?

Comment: Thanks for this!! Inner product how could I forget!